# Cross-compiling with CMake with an Ubuntu ARM VM for a Raspberry Pi

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi, arm, virtual-machine, cross-compiling

I am attempting to cross-compile a project on my M1 Mac using a Virtual Machine running Ubuntu 20.04 ARM server image. I believe my toolkit is not correct as I cannot get past compiling static-library test files.

I am using the aarch64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf toolkit from [ARM](https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/gnu-a).

My CMake file is as follows:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)

set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING TRUE)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR "armv8")

SET(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE "STATIC_LIBRARY")

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /opt/pi-cross-compile/gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-aarch64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-10.3.1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /opt/pi-cross-compile/gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-aarch64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-g++)


SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH $ENV{RASPBIAN_ROOTFS})
```

and my error when running CMake is:

```
- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.3.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.3.1
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/pi-cross-compile/gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-aarch64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-10.3.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/pi-cross-compile/gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-aarch64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-10.3.1 - broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/opt/pi-cross-compile/gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-aarch64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-10.3.1"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/parallels/kodlab_mjbots_sdk/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-FZkX11
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/cmake -E env VERBOSE=1 /home/parallels/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/bin/make -f Makefile cmTC_070a2/fast && /home/parallels/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/bin/make: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this the wrong toolbox? Or is my CMake file not configured correctly for cross-compilation using this toolbox. Thanks!

I have tried completely disabling the test program checks, but I didn't think that was the issue. CMake is complaining about the syntax of the make file inside the raspberry pi at the end of the error, which to me seems like it can't read the binary correctly with the cross-compiling toolbox I provided.